# CSS - "#" sign before property

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is a CSS property starting with a hash (#) valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161412/is-a-css-property-starting-with-a-hash-valid)

I tried looking around here on Stackoverflow.com but couldn't find anything related to my question. The open web wasn't any better either, although there was an answer on Yahoo! Answers the 'answer' didn't really say anything other than *"[`#` is for IDs]"* (no need to post the link of course).

This is a bit more advanced.

When reviewing the CSS code from a co-worker I found he used the `#` sign before several CSS properties.

What does the `#` sign before property do? That's gotta be some IE targeting hack I'm assuming.

For example:

```
.selector { #property:value; }
```

or well:

```
.headings { #margin-top:10px; }
```

I thought I knew a lot about CSS but this one caught me by surprise, especially that there's isn't any documentation of this case out there on the open web other than that answer in Yahoo! Answers.

Any info about this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update**

It turns out that `#property` is for IE7 or less, quoting from [Paul Irish](http://paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/):

> Update 2009.11.10 – Added #prop: value IE<=7 hack. I prefer it much
>   less to *prop.

---

Putting `#` before properties must be a hack for some browser. Other similar hacks include `_` (for IE6 and below), `*` (for IE8 and below), etc.

For more info, see:

- [Browser-Specific CSS Hacks](http://paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/)

Comment: CSS hash hack: http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/csshacks/hash

Comment: @Stefan: Interesting, yep that's hack.

Comment: For IE7 then, didn't know this one. I knew about `*+html` and `*property` but not `#property`. This is a case of SBBB :). Thanks Sarfaz. @Stefan, man, couldn't find that page, thanks man, gave you a 'up' vote.