# Why do we use (#) before CSS properties?

Tags: css

I have a question regarding the selector definition below:

```
.button-enable { 
    #padding-left: 15px;
    #padding-right: 15px;
    #padding-bottom: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I need to do some cleanup on the selector above and was wondering why someone would use # before the padding attributes? The problem that I have with this notation is that my eclipse css formatter doesn;t seem to recognize this notation. Is the # sign meaningful to any of the available browser?

Thanks

Comment: It's a hack/trick for targeting particular browsers: [IE6 - IE10pp4 hacks](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6024727).

Answer (score 2):

It's a hack for IE6 and below: [see this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802800/css-sign-before-property) Would definitely *not* recommend using this method for supporting these browsers if possible. You're better off with conditional stylesheet rules.

Comment: IE6?? Instead, insert something like `#computer:power-off;` </joke>