# What is #float:none and #display:inline etc in css. How is it different from float:none, display:inline, etc?

Tags: css

While I was at the CSS of CKE editor, noticed some CSS like `.cke_toolgroup{#float:none;#display:inline;}`

```
.cke_toolgroup{#float:none;}
```

I am curious about the `#` symbol here. We know the `float:none` or `display:none` would have done the job.

As far as I can see, `#` are usually used to represent id. But this is not used in that context.

What could possibily be the meaning of the `#` in this context?

Comment: please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161412/is-a-css-property-starting-with-a-hash-valid